# create arraycollection with different name

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I would like to create a new AC instance with a dynamic variable which is nca1, nca2, etc. Without define using hardcode variable name, it is possible to do that in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are missing the point here, getDefinitionByName gives you a class instance, you cannot create a variable with a dynamic name this way.

This is how you create an instance per reflection:

```
var symbolClass: Class;
var s: ArrayCollection;

symbolClass = getDefinitionByName("mx.collections.ArrayCollection") as Class;
s = new symbolClass();
```

If you wan't to have dynamic variables you'd better look at Dictionary and use it to save your values using strings as keys.

**EDIT**

You have now removed the code snippet, so that for others my code may doesn't make sense: but you know what I mean at least.

Dynamic variables in a loop is a different question - still you could use a Dictionary to save your data and yes you could dynamically create its content in a loop.

Comment: Ya, I was mistakenly thought it was getdefinitionbyname, I know how to create this code snippet as I been using them in my previous project. So here the actuall question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001518/define-unique-variable-name