# Define unique variable name

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

How to create a dynamic ArrayCollecton instance that use unque naming: ac1, ac2..ac999 whether user click a button. Without having to use hardcode variable name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [create arraycollection with different name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001385/create-arraycollection-with-different-name)

Comment: now it is - he created a new answer after editing the old one, previously they were different.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamically named variables on dynamic classes like this:

```
package
{
    dynamic public class Test
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            this["a"] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

now you could use this class:

```
var t: Test = new Test();
trace(t.a);
```

you'll notice that t has a property named "a" and its value is 1.

So using a dynamic class you could create a dynamically named properties in a loop. But I would say this is not better than using a dictionary to save you ArrayCollections so you might as well go straight for dictionary.

Comment: does this work if I want to just copy original AC to unique AC? As such ac1 = orgAC, ac2 = orgAC, ac3 = orgAC, so on...

Comment: it will work to make new references to the same object but not new copies. For this you would have to make, well, copies not references. Even if you make copies of the original arrays it doesn't mean you have copy, it depends on what is in the arrays. Google about shallow vs deep copy to decide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibly better way is use a dictonary to hold the instances by key name.

```
var _htArrayMap:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
_htArrayMap["ary1"] = [1,2,3,4];
```

you can use a string variable as the key.

Dictionaries in as3 are incredibly powerful, and efficent.

Comment: actually, I take that back, you can use absolutely anything as the key, I just tend to use strings for my own sanity while debugging.